# Java - Create package inside another package

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I am usign NetBeans and I would like to create **and place** a package within another package.

That's very easy but once created, the inner package is placed outside.

I do create an inner package by right click on the "taindicators" package

[image]

It seems allright, new package name "rsi" is going to be created inside "taindicators", but once finish the new package goes outside.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks.

[image]

**Edit:**

No changes even display project as Reduced Tree, rsi package is still outside

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Found (maybe) a solution: instead of creating a new package, I have created a folder, and it is now placed correctly.

I hope there are no great differences from packages to folders

[image]

Comment: I don't think 'outside/inside' has any actual meaning here.  AFAIU that is just Netbeans way of representing them.

Comment: Well, to me it would be a lot better to have packages listed visually inside a "parent". I will have to create maybe 100 packages and it will be a mess if it all will be created outside.

Answer (score 4):

Try this steps:
Right click on Project explorer -> View Java Packages as -> Reduced tree.

Answer (score 0):

To change the java package structure in web or java projects, right click on area below source packages, near to any package (but not on the package itself).

[image: Netbean packag structure]

right click>View java Package as>tree